# How do `map` and `reduce` methods work in Spark RDDs?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, closures

Following code is from the quick start guide of Apache Spark.
Can somebody explain me what is the "line" variable and where it comes from?

```
textFile.map(line => line.split(" ").size).reduce((a, b) => if (a > b) a else b)
```

Also, how does a value get passed into a,b?

Link to the QSG http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html

Comment: As @Tyth says "Maybe you should read some scala collection introduction first." I don't mean this to be dismissive, but instead to say you're in for a world of pain if you try anything non-trivial with Spark without at least a basic knowledge of the language you're using to do it with.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

First, according to your link, the `textfile` is created as

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("README.md")
```

such that `textfile` is a `RDD[String]` meaning it is a resilient distributed dataset of type `String`. The API to access is very similar to that of regular Scala collections.

### So now what does this `map` do?

Imagine you have a list of `String`s and want to convert that into a list of Ints, representing the length of each String.

```
val stringlist: List[String] = List("ab", "cde", "f")
val intlist: List[Int] = stringlist.map( x => x.length )
```

The `map` method expects a function. A function, that goes from `String => Int`. With that function, each element of the list is transformed. So the value of intlist is `List( 2, 3, 1 )`

Here, we have created an anonymous function from `String => Int`. That is `x => x.length`. One can even write the function more explicit as

```
stringlist.map( (x: String) => x.length )
```

If you do use write the above explicit, you can

```
val stringLength : (String => Int) = {
  x => x.length
}
val intlist = stringlist.map( stringLength )
```

So, here it is absolutely evident, that stringLength is a function from `String` to `Int`.

**Remark**: In general, `map` is what makes up a so called Functor. While you provide a function from A => B, `map` of the functor (here List) allows you use that function also to go from `List[A] => List[B]`. This is called lifting.

### Answers to your questions

> What is the "line" variable?

As mentioned above, `line` is the input parameter of the function `line => line.split(" ").size`

More explicit
`(line: String) => line.split(" ").size`

Example: If `line` is "hello world", the function returns 2.

```
"hello world" 
=> Array("hello", "world")  // split 
=> 2                        // size of Array
```

> How does a value get passed into a,b?

`reduce` also expects a function from `(A, A) => A`, where `A` is the type of your `RDD`. Lets call this function `op`.

What does `reduce`. Example:

```
List( 1, 2, 3, 4 ).reduce( (x,y) => x + y )
Step 1 : op( 1, 2 ) will be the first evaluation. 
  Start with 1, 2, that is 
    x is 1  and  y is 2
Step 2:  op( op( 1, 2 ), 3 ) - take the next element 3
  Take the next element 3: 
    x is op(1,2) = 3   and y = 3
Step 3:  op( op( op( 1, 2 ), 3 ), 4) 
  Take the next element 4: 
    x is op(op(1,2), 3 ) = op( 3,3 ) = 6    and y is 4
```

Result here is the sum of the list elements, 10.

**Remark**: In general `reduce` calculates

```
op( op( ... op(x_1, x_2) ..., x_{n-1}), x_n)
```

#### Full example

First, textfile is a RDD[String], say

```
TextFile
 "hello Tyth"
 "cool example, eh?"
 "goodbye"

TextFile.map(line => line.split(" ").size)
 2
 3
 1
TextFile.map(line => line.split(" ").size).reduce((a, b) => if (a > b) a else b)
 3
   Steps here, recall `(a, b) => if (a > b) a else b)`
   - op( op(2, 3), 1) evaluates to op(3, 1), since op(2, 3) = 3 
   - op( 3, 1 ) = 3
```

Comment: Great answer but I should say this:
   - each partition is processed sequentially element by element
   - multiple partitions can be processed at the same time either by a single         -worker (multiple executor threads) or different workers
You need to make n partitions if you want to process one element per time

Comment: Probably one of the finest answers I've read on SO.  Thank you, sir.

Comment: So your query returns the maximum word count in a line. Great ans , Tq

Answer (score 7):

`Map` and `reduce` are methods of RDD class, which has interface similar to scala collections.

What you pass to methods `map` and `reduce` are actually anonymous function (with one param in map, and with two parameters in reduce). `textFile` calls provided function for every element (line of text in this context) it has.

Maybe you should read some scala collection introduction first.

You can read more about RDD class API here:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

Answer (score 1):

what **map** function does is, it takes the list of arguments and map it to some function. Similar to map function in python, if you are familiar.

Also, File is like a list of Strings. (not exactly but that's how it's being iterated)

Let's consider this is your file.

```
val list_a: List[String] = List("first line", "second line", "last line")
```

Now let's see how **map** function works.

We need two things, `list of values` which we already have and `function` to which we want to map this values. let's consider really simple function for understanding.

```
val myprint = (arg:String)=>println(arg)
```

this function simply takes single String argument and prints on the console.

```
myprint("hello world")
hello world
```

if we match this function to your list, it's gonna print all the lines

```
list_a.map(myprint)
```

We can write an anonymous function as mentioned below as well, which does the same thing.

```
list_a.map(arg=>println(arg))
```

in your case, `line` is the first line of the file. you could change the argument name as you like. for example, in above example, if I change `arg` to `line` it would work without any issue

```
list_a.map(line=>println(line))
```