# Unexpected results in Spark MapReduce

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce

I'm new to Spark and want to understand how MapReduce gets done under the hood to ensure I use it properly. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32520848/5880417) provided a great answer, but my results don't seem to follow the logic described. I'm running the [Spark Quick Start](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/quick-start.html) guide in Scala on command line. When I do line length addition properly, things come out just fine. Total line length is 1213:

```
scala> val textFile = sc.textFile("README.md")

scala> val linesWithSpark = textFile.filter(line => line.contains("Spark"))

scala> val linesWithSparkLengths = linesWithSpark.map(s => s.length)

scala> linesWithSparkLengths.foreach(println)

Result:
14
78
73
42
68
17
62
45
76
64
54
74
84
29
136
77
77
73
70

scala> val totalLWSparkLength = linesWithSparkLengths.reduce((a,b) => a+b)
    totalLWSparkLength: Int = 1213
```

When I tweak it slightly to use (a-b) instead of (a+b),

```
scala> val totalLWSparkTest = linesWithSparkLengths.reduce((a,b) => a-b)
```

I expected -1185, according to the logic in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32520848/5880417):

```
List(14,78,73,42,68,17,62,45,76,64,54,74,84,29,136,77,77,73,70).reduce( (x,y) => x - y )
  Step 1 : op( 14, 78 ) will be the first evaluation. 
     x is 14 and y is 78. Result of x - y = -64.
  Step 2:  op( op( 14, 78 ), 73 )
     x is op(14,78) = -64 and y = 73. Result of x - y = -137
  Step 3:  op( op( op( 14, 78 ), 73 ), 42) 
     x is op( op( 14, 78 ), 73 ) = -137 and y is 42. Result is -179.
  ...
  Step 18:  op( (... ), 73), 70) will be the final evaluation.
     x is -1115 and y is 70. Result of x - y is -1185.
```

However, something strange happens:

```
scala> val totalLWSparkTest = linesWithSparkLengths.reduce((a,b) => a-b)
totalLWSparkTest: Int = 151
```

When I run it again...

```
scala> val totalLWSparkTest = linesWithSparkLengths.reduce((a,b) => a-b)
totalLWSparkTest: Int = -151
```

Can anyone tell me why the result is 151 (or -151) instead of -1185?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It happens because subtraction is neither associative nor commutative. Lets start with associativity:

```lisp
(- (- (- 14 78) 73) 42) 
(- (- -64 73) 42)
(- -137 42) 
-179
```

is not the same as

```lisp
(- (- 14 78) (- 73 42))
(- -64 (- 73 42))
(- -64 31)
-95
```

Now its time for commutativity:

```lisp
(- (- (- 14 78) 73) 42) ;; From the previous example
```

is not the same as

```lisp
(- (- (- 42 73) 78) 14)
(- (- -31 78) 14)
(- -109 14)
-123
```

Spark first applies `reduce` on individual partitions and then merges partial results in arbitrary order. If function you use doesn't meet one or both criteria final results can be non-deterministic.